# Why is ModelState.IsValid returning true but then saving changes throws a DbEntityValidationError?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

If I have two models (Post and Comment where a Post can have many comments) and in my Post controller I have a "LeaveComment" method... why does ModelState.IsValid return true in this method, but then db.SaveChanges() throws a DbEntityValidationException?

Does ModelState.IsValid only check the Post's validity and not the Comment that is being created's validity?

Some portions of my code below.

Edit:  It's also quite possible I'm taking the wrong approach entirely

Controller:

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    private MyEntityModelContainer db = new MyEntityModelContainer();

    [HttpPost, ActionName("LeaveComment")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LeavePostComment(int? id, string CommentText)
    {
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        post.LeaveComment(db, CommentText);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //Evaluates to true!

            db.Entry(post).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();  //throws DbEntityValidationException
        }
    }
}
```

Comment model:

```
public partial class Comment
{
    public Comment () {}

    public Comment(string comment)
    {
        this.CommentText = comment;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a comment")]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Post model:

```
public partial class Post
{        
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public void LeaveComment(MyEntityModelContainer db, string comment_text)
    {
        Comment comment = new Comment(comment_text);
        this.Comments.Add(comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into DbContext's ChangeSet who and what is failing to pass validation.

Comment: Unrelated to issue, why pass db into LeaveComment? And why not check validity before getting Post and calling LeaveComment?

Comment: In `LeaveComment` you are not assigning the comment to a post. I bet your database has a foreign key constraint on that (certainly should have.)

Comment: Jack Hughes -- this.Comments.Add(comment) should add the comment to the Post, no?

Comment: Andy Wiesendanger - Sorry, passing db is unnecessary in this context but was is in use in some other methods that were left out trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelState is the state of the POST data/ViewModel, not the State of your Entity Models. (see http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/).

To make the MVC validation work use a ViewModel for the Comment:

```
public class CommentViewModel : /* optional: */ IValidatableObject {

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a comment")]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    // example how to check for valid ID range
    // this should probably not be nullable if the Id is required by your code
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
       // optional: you can put any complex validation logic here ...
     }
}
```

Change the Signature of your action to

```
public ActionResult LeavePostComment(CommentViewModel viewModel)
```

Then `ModelState.IsValid` will check any validation attributes in the ViewModel and call the Validate() method (if defined).

Comment: CommentText is null, yes.  Trying to get the ModelState.IsValid to return false because of this...  But I think I see what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

ModelState works on the model for the given action. In your case, you don't have a model. You only pass in a string and use that to create a model. You could just check `string.isnullorempty(commenttext)`. Or, use a model instead.